# Using Autoincrement Primary keys as Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I'm creating a database and I'm not sure about one thing. I have an autoincrement primary key which I want to use as a foreign key. Should the foreign key also be autoincrement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreign key field **must not** be auto-increment. Auto-increment values imply that the field is not a foreign-key.

The purpose of auto-increment attributes is to generate a unique identity for new rows in the **current table**. The purpose of foreign keys is to uniquely identify rows in **another table**. They are very different things and you should read more about both and properly understand the difference.

Answer (score -1):

Auto-increment allows a unique number to be generated when a new record is inserted into a table.

Comment: Oh, but that is such a helpful answer to me. Foreign keys cannot be unique, right? So they should always be autoincremented?